# comparison of two aggregate function without group by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

suppose we have 3 tables,1st table is the master table below is the details

> MasterTable(Id,col1,col2)
>
> ChildTable1(Id,MasterId,Amount1)
>
> ChildTable2(Id,MasterId,Amount2)

i have to find the id from mastertable where `sum(chiletable1.Amount1)` should be greater than `sum(chiletable2.Amount2)`

i have written the query using groupby and having clause which givs the right data,

is there any other way to write the same query without groupby keeping in mind the performance issue if there is billons of records in the table.
following is my query

```
    select Mastertable.Id 
           from Mastertable,Childtable1,ChildTable2
           where Mastertable.Id=Childtable1.MasterId
                 and ChildTable1.MasterId=ChildTable2.MasterId
                 group by MasterTable.Id
                 having SUM(Childtable1.Amount1) > SUM(Childtable2.Amount2)
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that `group by` is the fastest way to do the query.

Comment: What if a specific MasterId exists in one of the two `ChildTables` but not both?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, *no*.

The reason is simple: *Without a `GROUP BY` you can't have `SUM()`s. (except maybe a grand total)*

(**EDIT**: Well, maybe a stored procedure with loops, cursors and the like, but *that* would definitely be an overkill! ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're going to have to group at *some* point, so I don't know why you don't want to group at all.

You could *try* grouping by the IDs in the child tables:

```
SELECT M.Id
FROM Mastertable M
INNER JOIN (SELECT MasterID, 
                   SUM(Amount) Amount 
            FROM Childtable1 
            GROUP BY MasterID) C1
    ON M.Id = C1.MasterID
INNER JOIN (SELECT MasterID, 
                   SUM(Amount) Amount 
            FROM Childtable2 
            GROUP BY MasterID) C2
    ON M.Id = C2.MasterID
WHERE C1.Amount > C2.Amount
```

If there's either a foreign key back to `MasterTable` or an index on `MasterID` in the child tables this is likely going to be the fastest way without pre-aggregating via snapshots or some other method.